# ask ubuntu message management

Tags: discussion

When I'm on my phone I can't effectively answer messages because A) I'm all thumbs and B) there is no Ubuntu on my phone. So I put a star on the message hoping to come back to it later only I don't know how to search for star messages when I'm back on my laptop.

When I post a comment on a question I'd like to know a couple days later which ones I didn't get a comment back from the OP. I'd like to check if it's been solved or if the OP needs still needs help. I don't know how to do this.

I wonder if the >1.5k club has any suggestions :D

Comment: Title vs. Content is unclear, are you asking how to find the favorites when you're back at your computer, or something else?

Comment: Yes specifically I want to flag Q&A to read later, under the general heading of "message management". Others are welcome to offer other suggestions for how they manage messages and they might not use the star function. This could be expanded into a feature-request tag too I guess.

Comment: Now you have 1.5k rep exactly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starred messages exist [inside your profile under the Favorites category](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix?tab=favorites).  You can access them by going to your own profile, going to the "Activity" tab, and then the "Favorites" tab below.  You're not the only one using favorites for this type of thing, I am too.

Comment: I hope I'm not one of your bad favorites :p Thanks for the tips. Thought about you when I heard Arnold Palmer died yesterday, he was from your state I believe.